# How to get the line number of a syntax error when the error occurs during javascript "import" by the browser

Tags: javascript, error-handling, syntax-error

Is there a way to determine which line number is causing a syntax error, when the error is being generated by the browser during a JavaScript "import"?

Catching the error object and inspecting it does not help (at least not on Chrome), since the error object offers just a message, and no other info.

Comment: If you really, really need to dynamically get the line number into a variable, and no one else can offer a simple solution, you can always use a Javascript parsing library like Acorn, which would be capable of finding syntax errors. Then, you can just load the Javascript file as plain text and feed it into acorn to look for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

For any file that is being imported and is suspect, load it using html.  The debugger will catch the error, and there will be a file-name and a line-number associated with the error message in the debugger console.  (Works in Chrome debugger).

So, put something like this in "index.html" (or your equivalent of "index.html"):

```
<script src="js/suspect.js" type="module"></script>
```

Do this early in the html, before the regular JavaScript gets loaded.

Syntax errors occur before all other types of errors.  As soon as all syntax errors have been fixed, it is likely other types of errors will start to show up.  At that point, immediately remove the added  line.